# vue-paginate load nested array vue.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, pagination, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to use the vue-paginate component from https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-paginate .

I want to create pagination for the questions I load from firebase. The declaration is here:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    quiz: {
      questions: [],
      answers: [],
      title: ''
    },
paginate: ['questions']
    }
```

Questions are in this form:

```
questions" : [ {
    "q_options" : [ "Yes", "No", "Don't know" ],
    "q_text" : "My organisation blah blah", 
     ...
  },{
    "q_options" : [ "Yes", "Maybe", "Don't know" ],
    "q_text" : " blah blah", 
     ...
  }]
```

And I'm calling it like this in the template:

```
    <paginate name="quiz" :list="quiz" :per="2">
  <li v-for="(quest,index) in paginated('quiz.questions')">
    {{ quest.q_text }}
  </li>
</paginate>
```

So, I'm getting the following errors:
[vue-paginate]: 'quiz.questions' is not registered in 'paginate' array. 
(found in root instance)  vue-paginate.js:21:6
[Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "list". Expected Array, got Object. 
(found in component )

How should I add/register the quiz.questions in the paginate('') array?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a computed to expose the `questions` outside of the quiz.

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    quiz: {
      questions,
      answers: [],
      title: ""
    },
    paginate: ["questions"]
  },
  computed:{
    questions(){
      return this.quiz.questions
    }
  }
});
```

Here is a working [example](https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/eWWvQm?editors=1010).

Additionally, `list` in the `paginate` component needs to be an array. You cannot tie it to your `quiz` object. I modified the template to look like this:

```
<paginate name="questions" :list="questions" :per="1">
  <li v-for="(quest,index) in paginated('questions')">
    {{ quest.q_text }}
  </li>
</paginate>
```

Comment: Didn't think about the computed property! Really simple and good way. Thank you!!!

Comment: In each new page, the index for the questions starts at 0 again. Is there any way that the index of every question in a new page to just continue to increment?

Comment: I want to save the responses in an array responses[] and with this implementation, it's replacing e.g. the responses[0] that I selected in the 1st question of the 1st page with the response of the 1st question of the 2nd page, etc. If e.g. there are 70 questions, I paginate them (5 in each page), how would I be able to store them in the array responses[69] one after the other? I use v-model: "responses[index]" when I select a response of a question in every radio group.

Comment: @linous `index` is generally a very bad way to reference things in arrays in Vue for precisely this reason.  Indexes change. Use an `id` property on each question and store the `id` in your response. Or store the response in the question itself.